# map/unordered_map with non-movable, default constructible value type

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move

**Update**: It appears, in 23.5.4.3 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) that the `m[1]` version should be valid

**Update2**: `m[1]` is working with gcc4.9.1

specifically, `std::mutex`.   Let's say I want to have a `std::unordered_map<int, std::mutex>`.  Is this possible?

I can't seem to add a `mutex` to the `map` without triggering an error on a deleted copy constructor at some level, either of the `mutex` or of the intern `std::pair` holding the mutex.

```
m.emplace(1);
m.emplace(1, {});
m[1];
```

all fail to compile.  All I really want is for the `mutex` to be constructed in-place inside the `map`.

I would prefer to not use `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>` but I know it's possible that is my best option.

Added:  a full example with `operator[]` which fails for me under gcc and clang

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::mutex> m;
    m[1];

    return 0;
}
```

the most relevant parts of the error from clang3.5

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:126:35: error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::mutex'
        : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(__y) { }
                                         ^      ~~~
...

f.cpp:6:6: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__detail::_Map_base<...>::operator[]' requested here
    m[1];
     ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/mutex:163:5: note: 'mutex' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
    ^
```

and from gcc 4.7.2

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/utility:72:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:38,
                 from f.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&) [with _U1 = int; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = std::mutex]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:273:72:   required from ‘constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = std::mutex; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = std::mutex; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type = int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:463:24:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](_Key&&) [with _Key = int; _Pair = std::pair<const int, std::mutex>; _Hashtable = std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, std::mutex>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::mutex> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::mutex> >, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type = std::mutex]’
f.cpp:6:8:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:126:45: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
In file included from f.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/mutex:163:5: error: declared here
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/utility:72:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:38,
                 from f.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = std::mutex; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type = std::mutex; typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T1>::__type = int]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:463:24:   required from ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](_Key&&) [with _Key = int; _Pair = std::pair<const int, std::mutex>; _Hashtable = std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, std::mutex>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::mutex> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const int, std::mutex> >, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>; std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type = std::mutex]’
f.cpp:6:8:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:273:72: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = std::mutex; std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<int, std::mutex>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:120:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = int; _T2 = std::mutex; std::pair<_T1, _T2> = std::pair<int, std::mutex>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:120:17: error: use of deleted function ‘std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)’
In file included from f.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/mutex:163:5: error: declared here
```

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes `unordered_map` only relinks its internal nodes on rehashing; it doesn't change references.

Comment: `m[1];` works for me. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d48a42bc78f55d1

Comment: Guess you need to upgrade to GCC 4.8.

Comment: Or use libc++. I studied the code, I'm pretty sure it would work.

Comment: [clang seems to work fine with libc++.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5156f364b01957ea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options.

One is that the third thing you tried, `m[1]`, should compile. What error are you getting?

The second is to use `emplace` with the `piecewise_construct` constructor:

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(1), std::tuple<>());
```

This *should* work, although I consider it quite possible that there are standard libraries out there where it doesn't.

Comment: Why should `m[1]` compile?  On an `unordered_map` if the key `1` is missing, a default-constructed `std::mutex` must be created and a reference assigned to it.  Construcing a new entry in the `unordered_map` can cause your existing buckets to be reallocated, and that reallocation could involve moving elements from one bucket to another.  Unless we force the `unordered_map` to store each element in its own node, and making the map work with pointers to said nodes, this is unavoidable: which means everyone is paying for the cost of immovable objects, not just people who want to use them.

Comment: "Unless we force the unordered_map to store each element in its own node" - That's exactly what we're doing. 23.2.5/8 says: "Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements." The only way to not invalidate references is to keep every element in its own node and only manipulate pointers. Note further that the requirements only ask for movable/copyable for elements for very specific functions, not all inserting functions as would be the case if rehashing could move them.