# can't compile struct with std::atomic member with explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, initializer-list, explicit, stdatomic

I am exploring the use of std::atomic in a struct across translation units and have run into a constructor compile problem. When I try to use explicit instantiation, the compiler says they don't match. How do I match up the explicit instantiation and the A constructor?

```
#include <string>
#include <atomic>
#include <map>

struct A
{
  A( std::string strArg, bool onOffArg ) // added constuctor after compiler complained it couldn't find one that matched
    : str { strArg }, onOff { onOffArg } {}
  ~A() {}

  std::string str {};
  std::atomic< bool > onOff { false }; // (see Edit1, Remy Lebeau). error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::map<int,A,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,A>>>', 'No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous'
};
A( const A& oldA ) // (see Edit2, Eugene)
{
  str = oldA.str;
  onOff.store( oldA.onOff.load() );
}


int main()
{
  std::map< int, A > aMap
  {
    { 1, { "One", false } } // assuming inner braces are a match for A ctor
  };
}
```

Edit1:
Fixed atomic constructor.

Edit2:
Copy ctor was missing (see reply to Eugene comment). Also, `atomic`'s `store` and `load` need to be used instead of assign in copy ctor.

Comment: Your problem is that `atomic` is not copyable or movable, which make the map difficult to work with. I think it can still be constructed using `emplace`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22229773/459565.

Comment: @Eugene Not having a copy constructor was the problem. Didn't even need the move constructor for this simple example. By adding a constructor with parameters the copy and move ctors were automatically deleted. But they are needed, as you point out, for `atomic` to work. In my example I am instantiating using explicit initialization whose format for ctor parameters is inner braces. Also, the proper (simple) way to assign to an `atomic` member is by using `store` and `load`. See Edit2.

Comment: The design is suspicious. Using `atomic` implies multiple threads, but the copy ctor does not guarantee the flag and the string will be updated together atomically.

Comment: @Eugene Are you suggesting that the flag be made explicit in the copy ctor? And are you suggesting that the string assignment in the ctor be skipped? Makes sense.

Comment: I am suggesting that you may need to protect copy ctor and other operations writing `struct A` by a mutex instead of using the atomic flag.

Comment: @Eugene Got it. New topic though. By the way, be sure and put your answer as an Answer in order to get credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `struct A` is non-copyable and non-movable: its auto-generated copy and move ctors are deleted because `std::atomic` is non-copyable and non-movable. A map with a non-movable value type can be created, but many operations on it are disabled, including the construction from the initializer list.

The underlying design problem is your decision to use `std::atomic`flag as part of a struct. In a multi-threaded environment, you probably want to synchronize updates to all struct members. In this case, it is better to include a non-atomic flag in the struct, and protect the operations modifying the map with a mutex.

So, your struct could be just

```
struct A
{
   std::string str;
   bool onOff;
};
```

and you make a wrapper class containing both `std::map< int, A >` and a mutex, with non-const methods containing locks on the mutex.